# PhP TextArea each line with explode and foreach postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, foreach, textarea, explode

It's a very simple question.  I have a textarea. In this textarea are names. Every name in a new row.

```
Brad Pitt
LMFAO
Green Day
```

and so on...

I would like to put this names in a database. I tried it with explode() and foreach, but it didn't work. :/

Here is the code:

```
$kilencedik=array();
$kilencedik=explode('\n',$_POST['9']);
foreach($kilencedik as $nev9) {
    $adat9 = pg_escape_string($nev9);
    pg_query($kapcsolodas, "INSERT INTO diakok (nev, ev) values ('$adat9', '9')");
}
```

I'm using postgreSQL with PHP.

Comment: Have you tried to actually see what's in that variable?

Comment: your textarea's name should not be a number

Comment: That variable has:

kilencedik[0] = Brad Pitt
kilencedik[1] = LMFAO
kilencedik[2] = Green Day

with using PHP_EOL function. But if a name has "á" or "ő" char, it doesn't work :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['9']);

Using PHP_EOL is more compatilbe across platforms.

If you don;t want to use that you need to at least use double quotes around the \n instead of single quotes.  Using double quotes, PHP will interpret that as the newline character whereas using single quote will look for literal \n as string segment to explode on.

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted. It is generally best practice to use this constant as opposed to "\n" "\r\n" or whatever.

Comment: It works, but with just english letters. :/ If a name has "á" or "ő" letter it couldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It's a ' problem change '\n' to "\n".